# Is the any possible way how i can check that nprogress.js is done using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript

I'm stuck a bit with that issue. I need to stop my test scenario execution until progress bar is visible. Progress bar is handled by nprogress.js

I was thinking about to catch it (progress bar) as WebElement but i assume that i won't be able to find it in time because progress bar can be visible from 1 to 6 seconds and selenium will search the element longer that execution itself.

Is there any possible way how i can check nprogress.js execution status?

Answer (score 1):

The simple option would be to ask the devs to add a status variable in the javascript that you can call via javascript executor class. I wouldn't like that since it introduces code in the product that has no obvious reason and violates clean code guidelines but it would work. The other way would be a spin lock, just something along the lines of
`float EmergencyBreak = 0;
while(!driver.findElement(ProgBar).isDisplayed()&& EmergencyBreak<7){EmergencyBreak +=(1/5); Thread.sleep(200);}`.

This would wait at most 7 seconds (35 iterations of 1/5th of a second) but break out as soon as the progress bar appears. In the end it really depends on the specific application though.